# Можно ли убить GC в JAVA

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора, задание-на-собеседовании

Я проходил собеседование и интервьювер  задал вопрос, можно ли убить GC в Java. На дополнительный вопрос, должно ли жить приложение он ответил, да должно. Я сказал, что без пересобирания JDK это сделать нельзя, точнее какие-то догадки я построил, но чтобы приложение работало, я не знаю как это сделать. Интервьювер сказал, что можно и что нужно загуглить, в гугл ничего такого не нашел, пожалуйста подскажите.

Comment: Убить вряд ли, отключить можно.

Comment: ну допустим [можно вызвать](https://shipilev.net/jvm-anatomy-park/9-jni-critical-gclocker/) в JNI `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical` и потом не освободить, тогда некоторые реализации GC не будут работать (а некоторые подвесят vm). Еще можно всячески оттягивать конец увеличением кучи, сохранением ссылок на все создаваемые объекты и уходом в off-heap. Если бы GC в Hotspot выключался, никто не стал бы предлагать [EpsilonGC](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8174901).

Comment: но зато можно отключить работу `System.gc()` опцией командной строки :)

Comment: Можно использовать off-heap - нативную память, которую gc не видит. Не знаю, подходит ли это под "убить GC".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> No. You cannot kill a GC programmatically. The interviewer is
>   expecting some answer like:
>
> The garbage collection cannot be forced. The garbage collector runs in
>   low memory situations. When it runs, it releases the memory allocated
>   by an unreachable object. The garbage collector runs on a low priority
>   daemon (background) thread. You can nicely ask the garbage collector
>   to collect garbage by calling System.gc() but you can�t force it.
>
> Note: The only way you kill a GC is when you exit your application.
>   System.exit();

---

Нет. Вы не можете убить GC из кода. Интервьюер ждал ответ типо такого:

GC не возможно остановить. Он начинает работу когда остается мало памяти. Начиная работать он освобождает память от забытых (недостежимых, тех на которые не осталось ссылок) объектов. GC работает в потоке демона с низким приоритетом. Единственное, что вы можете - попросите его собрать мусор вызовом System.gc(), но остановить вы его не можете.

p.s. Хотя можете, используя одну секретную команду от гуру-разработки System.exit();

[исходник](https://coderanch.com/t/379409/java/GC-Kill)

---

Это единственное, что смог найти.

IMHO:
GC включается когда остается мало память. Если программа не использует всю память, то он не начнет работать, можно сказать, что он мертв, но это не так. А если все такие его неведомым образом убить, то узнаете вы это по OutOfMemoryError и приложение остановится

---

По следам идеи **@ViacheslavVedenin**, что будет с GC если в finalize

- остановить нить GC
- навечно зациклить нить GC
- бросить exception

По докам написал сам **@ViacheslavVedenin**, а я решил пойти путем экспериментов. И никакой разницы.

[лог нормальной работы](https://pastebin.com/5x5KaHX8)

[лог с `Thread.currentThread().stop();` в finalize](https://pastebin.com/CLFHqh3n)

[лог с `while(true);`](https://pastebin.com/rVqBfK7y)

[лог с `throw new RuntimeException();` в finalize](https://pastebin.com/tVdW61xq)

Если честно то особой разницы я не заметил, так, что думаю GC создавая новую нить для finalize не особо о ней заботиться и не следит. Когда она закончит работу объект будет удален. Причина по который нить завершиться его не волнуют, раз завершилась значит сделала все, что могла.

---

Добавлю так же ответы товарища **@Suvitruf**, чтобы заметнее были:

- GC можно отключить
- Гуглить по словам "Шипилёв", "GC без GC"
- [статья на jug.ru](http://jug.ru/2017/02/epsilon-gc)
- [статья на хабре](http://%09%20habrahabr.ru/post/321856)

Comment: GC можно отключить.

Comment: @Suvitruf поделитесь как.

Comment: Гуглить по словам "Шипилёв", "GC без GC".

Comment: https://jug.ru/2017/02/epsilon-gc/

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/321856/

Comment: @Suvitruf Как я понял, там рассказывается как запустить код без GC(на его место поставить Epsilon GC), но не как остановить его в уже запущенном коде. А исходя из контекста вопроса "должно ли жить приложение он ответил, да должно." - разговор о остановке GC в работающей программе

Comment: Можно сознательно заставить сборщик выкинуть OutOfMemory Exception, но при этом продолжить работу. GS не сможет ни собирать, ни создавать новые объекты, однако приложение прекрасно сможет жить и продолжать работать.

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin если честно, то никак не получается. Если в finalize поставить вечный цикл, то GC и правда выкидывает OutOfMemoryError, но сам он не отключается, он продолжает работать и на следующем же объекте он снова выкидывает OutOfMemoryError. Это конечно можно назвать работающей программой, с очень большой натяжкой. При создании любого нового объекта, любого вывода на экран будет выкидываться OutOfMemoryError каждый раз. Т.е. GC не отключается и не умирает, он продолжает бросать ошибки, при каждом вызове.

Comment: "любого вывода на экран будет выкидываться OutOfMemoryError каждый раз." нет не будет, со стеком работать можно, так же можно работать уже выделенными объектами в хипе. В теории можно сделать даже свой GS заняв весь heap под байтовый массив и потом как-то сериализовывать объекты в нем.

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin что странно вы говорите, что ваш код может оперировать данными которые были и что-то выводить на экран. У меня же вывод на экран так же выкидывает OutOfMemoryError, т.к. требуется создать объект String. Я думаю это уже зависит от того когда GC начал работать и сколько памяти осталось. Попробуйте добавить в цикле вывод разных данных в консоль (раз так 500-2000), ради экперементального интереса =)

Comment: @Виктор, разве `force` === `остановить`?

Answer (score 4):

Можно (правда не убить, а заставить выкинуть OutOfMemory и прекратить сборку мусора, при этом приложение сможет продолжить работу), вот пример:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test1 {

    private static class TestClass {
        private byte[] bytes = new byte[100000];
        public int i = 0;
        public static volatile boolean flag = true;

        protected void finalize() throws IOException {
            int i = 1;
            while (flag) {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        TestClass t1 = new TestClass();
        new Test1().test(0, t1);
    }

    private void test(int j, TestClass t1) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
                TestClass t = new TestClass();
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            j++;
            t1.i = j;
            System.out.println("I alive!!! " + t1.i);
            if( j > 100) {
                TestClass.flag = false;
            }
            test(j, t1);
        }
    }
}
```

Что тут происходит? По спецификации, сборщик должен выполнить `finalize` перед тем как удалять объекты, из-за бесконечного цикла `finalize`, он не сможет удалять объекты и начнет выкидывать OutOfMemoryError (впрочем можно просто использовать вечные ссылки на объекты). При этом новые объекты создавать не получится, но можно продолжать работать со старыми и стеком (см код в catch (OutOfMemoryError e)). В том числе переиспользовать уже существующие объекты, например сохранять новые данные в старых объектах (можно даже написать свои аналоги сишных new и delete, используя массивы байт как хранилище данных и "сериализованных" объектов).

Через какое-то время мы отключаем бесконечный цикл в финалайзерах и у нас сборка мусора и создание объектов выполняется как обычно.

Comment: Вы не совсем правы, он должен вызвать метод файналайз, но он вызывает это в отдельном потоке, так что гц нормально себя чувствует

Comment: Да, я знаю и в курсе что ошибка в этом потоке игнорируется, но если поток зависнет или будет закрыт принудительно, что будет делать GS? Я пока не нашел, что говорит спецификация.

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin чисто из фантазии, может сборщику пофигу на нити finalize, т.к. он ничего не может сделать если они упали, только Error выкинуть. Если они прервались - значит отработали и можно удалять объект. Ну а если бесконечно зависли, фиг знает, может тоже подвиснет и не закончит работу пока последний поток не завершится.

Comment: Я обновил ответ, если судить по документации при исчерпании тредов для финалайзеров, GS должен кидать OutOfMemoryError, возможно если его перехватить, то приложение еще будет работать, а вот GS нет. Но это, конечно, злобный грязный хак.

Comment: Потестил, `Thread.stop()` в `finalize()` поток финализации не убивает. `Thread.sleep` - приостанавливает и перестают собираться объекты, у которых определен `finalize()`. Остальные объекты собираются нормально. Можно еще вызвать `System.runFinalization()` - на каждый вызов будет запущен дополнительный поток финализации.

Comment: Можно использовать бесконечный поток в финалайзере. Сейчас выложу пример.

Comment: если вы добавите еще один класс объектов, без `finalize()`, то эти объекты будут собираться (можно напр. по колебаниям `Runtime.freeMemory()` или через `PhantomReference` отследить).

Comment: Хмм, ну если подходить формально, можно занять все свободную память в одни массив байт. При этом программа сможет хранить в нем данные и получать значения, но GS не сможет ничего собрать или выделить.